# How to merge most conflicts using --theirs or --ours?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

When resolving merge conflicts in Visual Studio, I often face the situation that 48 out of 50 conflicts are conflicts that I want to resolve by using the local file version, and only 2 files require line-by-line conflict resolving. So I resolve those two conflicts and then what - click on every of the 48 remaining conflicts and click on "keep local"? Is there something with much less than 96 clicks, git command line if necessary?

Comment: If you get that situation regularly, wouldn't it be a more sustainable approach to figure out where those conflicts are coming from in the first place? A proper git workflow and configuration should prevent those situations most of the time.

Comment: @anothernode yes, an unclean strategy is certainly the root cause. We also have some installer projects in our solution, those always cause merge trouble.

Answer (score 4):

I find kdiff3 to be a great merge conflict resolution tool. It will automatically resolve the simple conflicts and give you a 3way merge interface for the more tricky ones.

(I use it for my diffs too)

https://sourceforge.net/projects/kdiff3/

Git config to integrate (replace Mac paths with Windows paths if needed)

```
$ cat ~/.gitconfig
[user]
    name = xxxxx
    email = xxx
[merge]
    tool = kdiff3
[mergetool "kdiff3"]
    path = /usr/local/bin/kdiff3
[diff]
    guitool = kdiff3
[difftool "kdiff3"]
    path = /usr/local/bin/kdiff3
[difftool]
    prompt=false
```

From the command line run `git mergetool` from the conflicted repo and kdiff3 will take care of it from there.

If on a Mac you've installed kdiff3 by dragging it to your Applications folder, then a symlink can keep things clean:

```
ln -s /Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3 /usr/local/bin/kdiff3
```

**Update**

kdiff3 hasn't had much love in a while, so I've moved over to [p4merge](https://www.perforce.com/downloads/visual-merge-tool)
on mac, with the following git config

```
[merge]
  keepBackup = false
        tool = p4merge
[mergetool "p4merge"]
        cmd = /Applications/p4merge.app/Contents/Resources/launchp4merge "\"$PWD/$BASE\"" "\"$PWD/$REMOTE\"" "\"$PWD/$LOCAL\"" "\"$PWD/$MERGED\""
        keepTemporaries = false
        trustExitCode = false
        keepBackup = false
[diff]
    tool = p4merge
[difftool]
        prompt = false
[difftool "p4merge"]
        cmd = /Applications/p4merge.app/Contents/Resources/launchp4merge "\"$LOCAL\"" "\"$REMOTE\""
```